# In c#, how to sort list of doubles by mantissa?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

*How to sort list of doubles by the fractional part of the double.*
  *E.g:* For input `<1.2, 2.3, 1.12, 5.1>`, after sorting, the output
         should be `<5.1, 1.12, 1.2, 2.3>`

Comment: What have you attempted?  What is giving you trouble.  Or is it that you just want some one to to do the work for you?  Or question history seems to indicate the latter.

Comment: Do you know how to get the fractional part of a double? Do you know how to sort with a user-defined rule? Or can you Google these two bits of code? Put them together, and you have your answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can achieve this through `OrderBy()` and `Math.Truncate()` method as like the following. Where `x-Math.Truncate(x)` gives you the number after the decimal point and `OrderBy` will arrange them in the ascending order. Have a look at this [example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iCRA0H) and try yourself with the following snippet

```
 List<double> input = new List<double>(){1.2, 2.3, 1.12, 5.1};
 input = input.OrderBy(x=>x-Math.Truncate(x)).ToList();
 Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\n",input));
```

Or you can try this as well `.OrderBy(x=>x-(int)x)` instead for `OrderBy(x=>x-Math.Truncate(x)`

Answer (score 1):

`List` has an [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s(v=vs.110).aspx) of the `Sort()` method that takes an instance of an `IComparer<T>`.  The [interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer(v=vs.110).aspx) is quite easy to implement and will allow you to sort by whatever method you want:

```
public class MantissaComparer : IComparer<double>
{
    public int Compare(double x, double y)
    {
        return Comparer<double>.Default.Compare(x - Math.Truncate(x), y - Math.Truncate(y));
    }
}
```

Then consume the custom comparer like this:

```
input.Sort(new MantissaComparer());
```

I see the `linq` tag, but this solution is more reusable throughout your code should you find it necessary, while avoiding "over-engineering" due to the simple 'IComparer' interface.

Comment: Will woks charm. Nice implementation

Answer (score 1):

You can also try below without using `Math.Truncate`

```
var sortedlist = list.OrderBy(n => n - (int)n).ToList();
Console.Write(String.Join(",", sortedlist));
```